# How add node_exporter to prometheus-stack in kubernetes from other instance

Tags: devops, prometheus, monitoring, prometheus-node-exporter

I am trying to add a node-exporter postgres database to a prometheus-stack that resides in a kubernes cluster

I tried to add scrap config to valeus.yaml in chart but when I upgrade the chart nothing  worked. Someone connected an node-exporter  that is outside the cluster to Prometheus